# Expanding the file system partion in linux mint/ubuntu

Tags: partition

I am running out of space on my Linux filesystem partition. However, I have plenty of space in the home partition. My disk's structure is shown below.

I wonder whether it is possible to downsize the home portion and use this space for the filesystem. The issue is that the swap partition separates the home and file system portions. There is also a windows partition (where windows 7 lives).

**What is the best way of shifting, say 5 GB, from the home to the filesystem partition?**

Before ruining my disk structure, I was hoping for some advice from someone.

In response to oldfred below, this is the output of running

```
df -hT -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs

Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p7 ext4   28G   23G  3.5G  87% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat  176M   98M   79M  56% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p9 ext4  686G  216G  435G  34% /home
```

[image]

Comment: What do you have in / taking up all the space? Normally 30GB is plenty, if you are storing all your data in /home? Post this in question. `df -hT -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs` & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263276/list-files-and-folders-of-the-root-partion/1263327#1263327

Comment: If you're using a debian or ubuntu-like system, I suggest you run an `apt-get clean` before everything else. You may free up enough space to save you from having to shuffle GBs around.

Comment: @oldfred I have added the requested output. Also, the cleaning operations in the link did not free up substantial amounts of space. As far as I can see, most space is taken up by the ```usr``` folder (17 out of 24 GB) and ```var``` folder (4 out of 24 GB).

Comment: First, find out what's taking up all your space.  To repeat an earlier comment: 30 GB should be plenty for a Linux installation.

Comment: Most space is taken up by the ```usr``` folder (17 out of 24 GB) and ```var``` folder (4 out of 24 GB). Under ```usr```, ```texlive``` and ```texlive-doc``` are the biggest chunks (2.8 + 2.8 GB).

Comment: I so not have texlive, but if I install it, it says this including all the extra support files: "269 MB of additional disk space will be used" And my /var is 569M, but I houseclean all older logs regularly. And my /usr is 6.0G which is most of my 8.4G / (root). Are you installing as snaps & lots of snaps? I have no snaps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend removing the swap partition, using the 8 GiB of free space to extend your root partition and shrinking your home and creating a new swap partition in the freed space. Don't forget to edit `/etc/fstab` with the new swap path or UUID after that.

You can also shrink your home and then move the partitions around (GParted can do that, GNOME Disks doesn't support moving partitions) but it's more complicated and requires actually copying the data so it takes a lot of time even with NVMe.

You can't do this on partitions that are mounted so you'll need to use a Live CD. Make sure to backup any important data first. It should be safe operation, but you never know with storage.